# How to find Request Per second in apache2 on linode VPS(ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, apache2

How to find request per second on my linode VPS(ubuntu 12.04).I have apache2 with mysql,apc and memcache.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345546/how-to-get-requests-per-second-for-apache-in-linux

Comment: I tried it yesterday but it didnot work for me.